# How make my android video streaming application faster

Tags: android, video, video-streaming

Is there a code to make video streaming application faster when buffering, as if the application is automatically compresses the video when uploading? but the quality doesn't suffer much.

Thanks,

Comment: you want some magic. It can't be fast and high quality at a time. Or please specify, `faster` then what?

Comment: What I mean is, are all video streaming player the same? or what makes youtube, hulu and netflix's video player different in terms of streaming quality.

Comment: why you ask us? We didn't develop `youtube, hulu and netflix`. We can't know. ` the same` they for sure aren't the same. But only people who developed them know for sure how exactly. Others can only guess. Please specify what is your problem.

Comment: Thank you for your respond. I'm a newbie in android development, and currently I'm experimenting in video players and video streaming. Is  there any player aside from videoView in developing android app

Comment: I suggest to check on https://android-arsenal.com/tag/110?sort=created . There are a lot of libraries collected. I've linked a `video` libraries page.

Comment: That's a big help, I appreciate it very much. Thank you!